# How can I put a Webview below other views and scroll all views together

Tags: android, scroll, android-webview, android-scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I'm developing an android application there I have a webview below other views.

The whole content does not fit the screen so I want to enable some scrolling.

My layout file looks like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    <TextView .../>
    <TextView .../>
    <TextView .../>
    <TextView .../>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/about_detail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/contactInformation"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Should I use a Scrollview around my ConstraintLayout, or how can I do that?

Comment: It should be possible by adding a ScrollView as the firs child of your ConstraintLayout, and add further elements as children of the ScrollView.

Comment: I put a scrollview as the first child in my constraintlayout but now only the webview is scrollable and not the views coming before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try below code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView .../>
        <TextView .../>
        <TextView .../>
        <TextView .../>

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/about_detail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```